# How to control particular sentence with css

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a particular sentence and control font color with css. My code is below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body    {display:none;}
      .apple  {color:red;}  <- pattern a
      /* .banana {color:yellow;} */ <- pattern b
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    My favorite fruit is <span class="apple">apple</span>. <- sentence 1
    My favorite fruit is <span class="banana">banana</banana>. <- sentence 2
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to show only sentence 1 with pattern a and I want to show only sentence 2 with pattern b, but the result is that I can't see any sentences in my Web Browser.

How can I edit css and html to show sentences 1 and 2 with patterns a and b, respectively?

Comment: Do you really mean sentence, or word?

Comment: This is not a job for CSS unles you decide to split the two sentences into two elements. If you can't do that, use JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Remove `body    {display:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Appy a class a for the first sentence and class b for the second sentence. 
Below I've used `<p> but <div> could be used instead.`

```
<p class="a">My favorite fruit is <span class="apple">apple</span></p>
<p class="b">My favorite fruit is <span class="banana">banana</banana>>/p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the visibility of a random section of text with CSS. Even with JavaScript what you're asking for is hard without additional markup.

First, as @jaux says, you are hiding everything with

```css
body { display:none }
```

You need to remove that if you want anything to show up. Next, as @suspectus says, you will need to wrap each sentence in some sort of element. Even so, you can't do what you're asking for—hide a parent element based on child content—with pure CSS. You'd need JavaScript.

AFTER wrapping your sentences with discrete elements:

```html
<p>My favorite fruit is <span class="apple">apple</span></p>
<p>My favorite fruit is <span class="banana">banana</banana>>/p>
```

You would use JavaScript to find the parent element, e.g.:

```js
// Using jQuery
$('.apple').closest('p').hide();

// Using pure JavaScript
var apples = document.querySelectorAll('.apple');
for (var i=apples.length;i--;){
  var parentP = apples[i];
  while (parentP && parentP.tagName.toLowerCase()!='p') parentP = parentP.parentNode;
  if (parentP) parentP.style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can use similar work by setting the style on the owning paragraph (or span, or div, or whatever) to change other properties, like color.

Answer (score 0):

Remove body `{display: none;}` and apply it specifically to the sentence you want to hide.

I would use ids since you won't use it multiple times, but you can use classes to help you locate those `<p>` tags.

However, if you want to get cray cray - You can select them like this...

```
p:first-child { display:none; }
p:nth-child(2) { display: none;}
```

True, it looks weird. But it works.